# In an MS Word equation, where does the ‘dx’ go in an integral?

Tags: microsoft-word, equation-editor

When you enter an integral in an equation in Word, it recognises the integral as a function and gives you a greyed box to fill with the expression to be integrated. **But where should the ‘dx’ go?** Inside the grey box or after it? (See this screen grab.) Is there an intended convention here?

[image]

If you put ‘dx’ outside the greyed box, you get a nice little space before the ‘dx’, as when you use `\,` in latex to add a bit of whitespace for legibility. This is what I’m doing for now.

Answer (score 0):

Answer removed. Not much point posting to a site - even if it is a Q&A site - when the OPs cannot be bothered to respond.